# Decorator Pattern Help

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am working on an Oreilly's example

```
  using System;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using Given;

  // Decorator Pattern Example                        Judith Bishop  August 2007
  // Draws a single photograph in a window of fixed size
  // Has decorators that are BorderedPhotos and TaggedPhotos that can be composed and added
  // in different combinations

  namespace Given {

    // The original Photo class
    public class Photo : Form {
      Image image;
      public Photo () {
        image = new Bitmap("jug.jpg");
        this.Text = "Lemonade";
        this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Drawer);
      }

      public virtual void Drawer(Object source, PaintEventArgs e) {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(image,30,20);
      }
    }
  }

  class DecoratorPatternExample {

    // This simple BorderedPhoto decorator adds a colored BorderedPhoto of fixed size
    class BorderedPhoto : Photo {
      Photo photo;
      Color color;

      public BorderedPhoto (Photo p, Color c) {
        photo = p;
        color=c;
      }

      public override void Drawer(Object source, PaintEventArgs e) {
        photo.Drawer(source, e);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(color, 10),25,15,215,225);
      }
    }

    // The TaggedPhoto decorator keeps track of the tag number which gives it 
    // a specific place to be written

    class TaggedPhoto : Photo {
       Photo photo;
       string tag;
       int number;
       static int count;
       List <string> tags = new List <string> ();

       public TaggedPhoto(Photo p, string t) {
          photo = p;
          tag = t;
          tags.Add(t);
          number = ++count;
       }

       public override void Drawer(Object source, PaintEventArgs e) {
          photo.Drawer(source,e);
          e.Graphics.DrawString(tag, 
          new Font("Arial", 16), 
          new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 
          new PointF(80,100+number*20));
       }

       public string ListTaggedPhotos() {
          string s = "Tags are: ";
          foreach (string t in tags) s +=t+" ";
          return s;
       }
    }



    static void Main () {
      // Application.Run acts as a simple client
      Photo photo;
      TaggedPhoto foodTaggedPhoto, colorTaggedPhoto, tag;
      BorderedPhoto composition;

      // Compose a photo with two TaggedPhotos and a blue BorderedPhoto
      photo = new Photo();
      Application.Run(photo);
      foodTaggedPhoto = new TaggedPhoto (photo,"Food");
      colorTaggedPhoto = new TaggedPhoto (foodTaggedPhoto,"Yellow");
      composition = new BorderedPhoto(colorTaggedPhoto, Color.Blue);
      Application.Run(composition);
      Console.WriteLine(colorTaggedPhoto.ListTaggedPhotos());

      // Compose a photo with one TaggedPhoto and a yellow BorderedPhoto
      photo = new Photo();
      tag = new TaggedPhoto (photo,"Jug");
      composition = new BorderedPhoto(tag, Color.Yellow);
      Application.Run(composition);
      Console.WriteLine(tag.ListTaggedPhotos());
    }
  }
/* Output

TaggedPhotos are: Food Yellow                                                                                                  
TaggedPhotos are: Food Yellow Jug   
*/
```

Next Exercise is

**Assume that the Photo class was written with Drawer as a plain (not virtual)
method and it cannot be altered. Reconstruct Example 2-2 so that it works
under this constraint**

How can i do that ?

**My Approach**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using GivenWihInterface;


namespace GivenWihInterface
{
    interface IPhoto
    {
        void Drawer(object sender, PaintEventArgs e);
    }

    class Photo : Form, IPhoto
    {
        Image image;

        public Photo()
        {
            image = new Bitmap(@"c:\users\anishmarokey\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Design_Pattern_Decorator\DecoratorPattern_RealExample\Images\apple-6.jpg");
            this.Text = "Apple";
            this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Drawer);
        }
        public void Drawer(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, 20, 20);
        }
    }

    class BorderPhoto : Form, IPhoto
    {
        IPhoto pho;
        Color color;

        public BorderPhoto(IPhoto p, Color c)
        {
            pho = p;
            color = c;
            this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Drawer);
        }

        public void Drawer(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            pho.Drawer(sender, e);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(color, 10), 25, 15, 215, 225);
        }
    }
}
namespace DecoratorPattern_RealExample
{
    class DecoratorPatternWithInterface
    {
        static void Dispaly(GivenWihInterface.IPhoto p)
        {
            Application.Run((Form)p);
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            IPhoto component = new GivenWihInterface.Photo();
            Dispaly(component);

            component = new GivenWihInterface.Photo();
            IPhoto p = new GivenWihInterface.BorderPhoto(component,Color.Red);
            Application.Run((Form)p);
        }
    }
}
```

**is this the correct Way?**

Comment: Is this a home work question? Did you face any difficulties while implementing it? Please post your approach.

Comment: updated the question with my approach

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is an appropriate "decorator" implementation. The only thing I'd question is whether you actually need to inherit from `Form`, or whether implementing `IPhoto` is sufficient. Which can only be answered with more context.

Also, the hard-coded (dimensions?) values look like there may be a better way if some existing values are available somewhere.

The example itself is unusual, though - you've had to **introduce** the interface, which is pretty much as much of a change as you are trying to avoid; and the type handles an event **on itself**, which is bad practice. I almost wonder if they want you to hook into the event pipeline, but that wouldn't really be a decorator.

I suspect they want you to code against Form rather than the IPhoto you have introduced, which would allow you to decorate lots of things. But you would need to have a known method on Form to call, for example Paint() - except that is an event here, not a method so the name will be different. And again we could hook the event, but that isn't classic decorator usage.

Comment: could you please provide an example

Comment: Of? In the above, not without more context. The question is, as I tried to say several times, unclear in the intent.

Comment: one more question. What is the best way to study Design patterns and uml diagrams?

Comment: They are very different things, but anywhere... GOF would be a good start